# MVC Structure?

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, interface-builder

I am having some difficulty getting my head around the MVC structure.

What I am still struggling with is, when creating the Control to accompany the supporting code, does one need to include the Object within IB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of IB as a freeze-dried version of an object.  It is the object itself in visual form.  It's stored in the xib file and pulled out when referenced.

You don't NEED to use IB.  You can create an object and add it to a view without ever opening the visual tool (some people prefer to work that way).

Storyboarding carries this to an even greater level where you can create the interaction between views in the form of segues.

Comment: Richard,
Thanks for your response.  One further related question:

If you had a single window but has an unrelated TableView & ImageView, would I create a separate controller for each control?